# as3 Clearing all colors but one

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, drawing

I am creating a vector drawing painting app and I have created a button that clears all the graphics (drawings) on the canvas. So basically, I just want to use pure white to "erase" all the drawings. Now I know there's other methods, but using this method is very important for future purposes. Now I want to clear the board of all graphics but the color,white, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the best way to do this is to have two graphics you draw in, one for white, and one for everything else, that way you only clear the one. Not sure what you mean exactly since if the board is white, and you can already erase with white, what you are trying to accomplish by not clearing the white. Anyways add some more details if my suggestion doesn't work for you problem.

Comment: Ah, I tried this and it didn't work. See, the white is to cover up text written by the user (there isn't any other way on vector drawings to erase the text). The text is also on a different layer. So when I use white on another layer, the text appears under the white. I need text to appear over everything, yet can still be erased by white (if this makes any sense)

Comment: Ok could you walk me through all the layers you have and what they are for? A drawing layer (for drawing with any color), a text layer (for text entered by the user), and an "erasing" layer (to paint white over everything)? Could you explain the layers a little more and what problems you are running into in detail? Thanks.

Comment: You have the layers correctly, those are all the layers I have. The drawing layer is for the canvas, it does as you says, draws any color. The text layer is to hold the text (this layer is transparent). I need a separate layer for the text because you cannot use white on the drawing layer to erase text. Now this worked fine at first, but I have a button that clears the board of all graphic data (including white), which reveals the text again (Because the button does not clear text). If it were possible to clear all colors except white, this would work as I want it to.

Comment: Can't you just clear the textfield when you clear the canvas? Does the text need to stay as an editable layer? If not another idea is to use draw(mcContaingText) to add the text to the layer with all the other art. What are the rules/limitations of the text layer?

Comment: Well I would clear the textfield at the same time if it were possible, but text isn't a graphics object so graphics.clear() doesn't work. Since it is an actual canvas textfield.text = "" is not an option (since the text can be pasted down). And unless i'm mistaken you cannot use .draw on a graphic object (though I may be mistaken on that). And what do you mean by rules and limitations exactly?

Comment: You cant, I thought you underlying "paining" layer was bitmapdata. Perhaps you could composite all your layers onto on bitmapdata and display that? When you say it's a canvas textfield what do you mean? Canvas as in HTML or some AS3 class?

Comment: I've tried using bitmapdata in the past and was unsuccessful at doing anything I wanted (So I just decided not to use it). By canvas I just meant the drawing layer. And let me fix my error : Since it's an actual canvas, textfield.text = "" is not an option. I'm worried there may not be a solution to this.

Comment: If you want your app to be efficient and usable by people you'll have to use bitmapdata. There's no other ways, drawing and displaying vector has limits (the CPU itself) and once that limit is reached the app will lag and maybe even crash in some cases.